# Traversing in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux shell scripting! Can anyone tell me how to:

1. traverse a folder with multiple `xml` files.
2. after traversing, check for given string.
3. if the given string is present, display the files **with** given string

Comment: elaborate your question: what is the search string?

Comment: ls <folder-name> | grep <search-string>

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, lets say i have 10 .xml files in a folder, say abc! now, i have to write a script which checks if a string that says "display_name = Question", is present in the all the files of the folder. if present, i need to display the files with said string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -o "display_name = Question" /path/to/abc/*.xml
```